# Can' t send Email through android app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm using C# for Visual studio, and i wanted to send an Email through my app, but i always get an error

here's my code

```
Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);

button.Click += delegate
{
    var email = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);
    email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraEmail, new string[] { "person1@gmail.com", "person2@gmail.com" });
    email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraCc, new string[] { "person3@gmail.com" });
    email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraSubject, "Hello Email");
    email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText, "Hello user");
    email.SetType("message/rfc822");
    StartActivity(email);
};
```

and i always get this error

> Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=message/rfc822 flg=0x1 (has clip) (has extras) }

can someone help me?

Comment: If you want to test on a simulator you can look at installing Play/GApps/etc...(google search is your friend) in order to have a 'complete' Android experience. You can also look a using BlueStacks as a `test device` as it is a licensed Android player and comes with Google Play install so you can then install any other Play-based apps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I means that it can't find an activity to handle the action SEND.
Are you running this on code in a simulator? Try it on a physical device (make sure it has a mail client installed).

Also, I would surround your code in a **try/catch** block, to avoid crashing if there's no activity available to handle your intent.

** Update **

Here's an example. Put the try/catch block inside your delegate.

```
try
{
    var email = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);
        email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraEmail, new string[] { "person1@gmail.com", "person2@gmail.com" });
        email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraCc, new string[] { "person3@gmail.com" });
        email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraSubject, "Hello Email");
        email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText, "Hello user");
        email.SetType("message/rfc822");
        StartActivity(email);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Either ignore or log the error.
}
```

Comment: yes, i'm running this code in a simulator, and can you do me an example with the try/catch block?